# Secure way to accept payments on Django Heroku?

Tags: django, heroku, payment

I'm trying to accept payments on Django using Heroku.

I've had a ton of issues using Stripe because I don't know much about client-side/server-side and every time I get something that works, I have to expose my private key. I feel like there's no resource out there for this. Does anyone have something that can help?

Answer (score 0):

Typically any secrets you don't want to expose to users (like secret API keys) can be kept on your Django server backend and is not exposed to your application's users.

What's important to understand with Stripe is that there are two [kinds of API keys](https://stripe.com/docs/keys#obtain-api-keys): **publishable** API keys and **secret** API keys.

Per the stripe documentation:

| Key type | example | When to use |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Publishable | pk_test_TYooMQauvdEDq54NiTphI7jx | **On the client-side**. Can be publicly-accessible in your web or mobile app’s client-side code (such as checkout.js) to tokenize payment information such as with Stripe Elements. By default, Stripe Checkout tokenizes payment information. |
| Secret | sk_test_4eC39HqLyjWDarjtT1zdp7dc | **On the server-side**. Must be secret and stored securely in your web or mobile app’s server-side code (such as in an environment variable or credential management system) to call Stripe APIs. |

So, you would keep your secret key in your Django app only. Your frontend would either only call your backend or would only use the publishable key.

There are a few products that stripe offers for integrating payments into your app. You can look at the [Stripe Checkout quickstart](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout/quickstart) for code samples on how to properly use these keys in your app.

Comment: How would I "call my backend"?